# How to compare the values in a list and the value that is compared to will be inserted to the front or back if its larger or smaller?

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I am creating a function that inserts an element into a list only if the element to be inserted
is larger than any of the elements currently in the list. Larger can mean either greater
than when working with numeric values, or further down in the alphabet, when
working with textual values.

```
var names = new List();
function List(){
    this.dataStore = [];
    this.listSize = 0;
    this.pos = 0;
    this.append = append;
}
function append(element){

    for (i = 0; i > this.dataStore.value;++i){
        if (names.value == this.dataStore[i].value){
        this.dataStore[this.listSize++] = element;
        this.pos++;
        }
    }
}
function insert(element, after) {
    var insertPos = this.find(after);
    if (insertPos > -1) {
    this.dataStore.splice(insertPos+1, 0, element);
    ++this.listSize;
    return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
function find(element){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.dataStore.length;++i){
        if(this.dataStore[i]== element){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

names.append("Jascien");
console.log(names);
names.append("Jas");// i want to insert this value after its compared to the exiting values in the front of the first value or after it.
console.log(names);
names.append("John"); // also this one
console.log(names);
```

Comment: provide the input arrays and the output array you want for better understanding

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: i added a comment in the code to specify the input that i wanted to append in the list

Answer (score 0):

By numeric values you mean number as string, or number as Number. If number as Number, then I think it would be good to divide this condition check in two separate condition check, depending on type of data entered as element.

As written above, please provide some input and output arrays for better understanding what you expect from this function.

Comment: Hey eRtuSa, your answer looks like it would be better as a comment on the question. If you believe your answer is correct can you please elaborate on it by adding example solutions?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, but in above question I wasn't able to write comment because my reputation is less than 50. In this case I'll prepare my solution for this problem to earn some reputation to be able to write comments later to ask for more information needed to better understand a question.